# python error need more than one value to unpack

Tags: python

i have read all the other questions asked about this python error and none of them are helping me, i am a beginner on python and really need help. i have to find the average of some students results from a file and it comes up with the error more then one value to unpack on lines 4 and 7

```
fileName = classChoice + ".txt" # generate the name of the file to read
with open (fileName) as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        userName,score= line.split(' : ')
        scores[userName].append(int(score))
        total=0
    for (userName, score )in fileName:
        total=total+score
        average= total/len(fileName)
        print("the average is ", average)
```

Comment: What if there was no `:` present on a line? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: You are trying to unpack two values from a string, what do you expect would happen with `for (userName, score )in fileName:`?

Comment: you would need to show us the example file.

Comment: Please show us the error message and a selection of lines from the file that demonstrate this issue.

Comment: the error is Traceback (most recent call last):    File     "/Users/charlotteaston/Documents/year11/CharlotteKnight-2/results/average.py", line 14, in <module>
    for (userName, score )in fileName:
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: i have a text file called rat that contains the names of the three people who have taken the quiz e.g giles alice and miles and their score having taken the test, each person has taken the quiz more then once therefore i have to calculate the average of their scores

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues in your code.

```
userName,score= line.split(' : ')
```

This will fail, if the line does not contain `' : '`. For example, a line with `'Foo: 12'` will already fail because there is no space before the colon. You’re better off splitting by the colon only, and then trimming whitespace from the values:

```
userName, score = line.split(':')
scores[userName.strip()].append(int(score.strip()))
```

---

The other issue is with the following line:

```
for (userName, score )in fileName:
```

`fileName` is a string containing the file name of the file you opened before and read from. What you probably want to do is iterate through the dictionary `scores`. Note that you collected individual score values for each user, so the dictionary values are actually score lists. So you need to iterate through those again:

```
for userName, userScores in scores.items():
    total = 0
    for score in userScores:
        total += score
    average = total / len(userScores)
    print("the average for", userName, "is", average)
```

Answer (score 0):

The notation `a, b = l` will only work if `len(l) == 2` (for `a, b, c = l`, for `len(l) == 3` and so on).

Here, it looks like `line.split(' : ')` gives you a list containing only one value so it cannot be unpacked.

In the case of a string like `fileName`, the unpacking will happens at the character level. Here, `fileName` contains definitely more than 2 char (it is at least `".txt"` if classChoice is empty) so it cannot work. Here you should get `ValueError: too many values to unpack`.